# how to pass a javascript object to a Java Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, tomcat, servlets

I have a javascript object that i want to pass to a java Servlet,
how can i perform this operation ?
I have already tried few things but didnt work out.

Here is my code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'TestUrl',
    data: {
        object: myJavaScriptObject
    },
    type: 'GET'
});
```

and in the servlet (doGet method)

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String result = request.getParameter("object");
    System.out.print(result);
}
```

but i just get null in the console.

I'm also interested on how to perform the opposite operation, pass a java object in the servlet to a JavaScript Object.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try using post instead of get.

Comment: I dont think "object" will be a request parameter, but a query string.

Answer (score 1):

Change GET to POST for sending data.

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'TestUrl',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        object: myJavaScriptObject
    },
    type: 'POST'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
                        url: 'TestUrl',
                        method: 'post',
                        data: {
                            object: myJavaScriptObject
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            if(data.success) {
                //process your data here
                }
                        }
                    });
```

List item